# Cant disable laptop keyboard in device manager

Tags: laptop, keyboard, device-manager

When I select built in keyboard in device manager I got only uninstall option. When I clicked it, I got a prompt with uninstalling device. Then I click yes, than I got message that that device will be uninstalled and that it needs reboot. Then laptop reboots by itself, however keyboard every time is not disabled and is still in device manager.
I am logged as Administrator.

Comment: I have external wireless keyboard that I use on laptop btw.

Comment: A laptop keyboard normally cannot be disabled. The design point is that it may be the only input device available.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't be able to disable the keyboard in Device Manager, depending on the make and model it may be possible to disable it in the BIOS though. Have a look at your laptop's user manual for how to get into the BIOS, usually you hold <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> when powering it on. You might also be able to see which key to press on the splash screen before your OS starts.